# multivariate pearson correlation analysis

Tags: correlation

So I have got a set of data, which consists of the abundance of each butterfly species in each sampling point, and the temperature of their respective sampling point. Can I first do a Spearman correlation to test the effect of temperature on the overall abundance of butterflies then repeat it again with each species to assess the effect of temperature on species individually?

Comment: What is your sampling unit? Do you have multiple observations for each species?

Comment: sorry for that, I was a newcomer to statistics. This is an exercise of my course and all I got have been provided in the text. What do you mean by multiple observations?

Comment: I see, can you tell us how the data look like? What are in the rows and columns? Maybe, you can share with us sample data.